# jade undefined variable

Tags: node.js

Here is an example jade input:

The class variable is undefined

```
input.class(name="class", type="textfield", value="#{locals.class}")
```

This shows up as a form with undefined already set as the value. That's not what I want, if it's undefined then no text should appear.

I can also do this:

```
-if (locals.class) {
input.class(name="class", type="textfield", value="#{locals.class}")
- } else {
input.class(name="class", type="textfield", value="")
- }
```

But it seems fairly terrible/unusable if I have to do this for every input in every form across the app.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simple fix, you just have to have to remove the quotes and braces and it will print an empty string

```
input.class(name="class", type="textfield", value=locals.class)
```

Comment: But what if instead of setting an attribute value you're trying to output the variable unescaped like; !{locals.class}

Comment: @arkanciscan value!=locals.class

Comment: It took me a little while to verify to myself that I can put my variables there directly - passed in from the render() jade view call - without wrapping them in this notation: "#{myVar}" .. in part because it doesn't seem to given any error output even if you put an invalid var name.  But when using correct names, I simply put in the .jade file  **input( .., value=myVar)** and it works .. very cool, Thanks!